# RegEx Decimal or Fraction

Tags: java, regex

I cant make my regex pattern to be able to input decimal or fractions

this is my pattern: `\\d{0,5}([./]\\d{0,3})?`

My Target input is for decimal(12345.123), fraction(12345 12/12)

I also tried this pattern: `\\d{0,5}([.]\\d{0,3})?|\\d{0,5}^\\s([/]\\d{0,3})?$` but it didn't work..

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter;

public class Regex extends DefaultFormatter {

  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Matcher matcher;

  public Regex(Pattern regex) {
    setOverwriteMode(false);
    matcher = regex.matcher(""); // create a Matcher for the regular expression
  }

  public Object stringToValue(String string) throws java.text.ParseException {
      if (string == null || string.trim().equals("")) return null;
    matcher.reset(string); // set 'string' as the matcher's input

    if (! matcher.matches()) // Does 'string' match the regular expression?
      throw new java.text.ParseException("does not match regex", 0);

    // If we get this far, then it did match.
    return super.stringToValue(string); // will honor the 'valueClass' property
  }
}
```

then I use this for the JFormattedTextField

```
Pattern decFraction = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,5}([.]\\d{1,3}|(\\s\\d{1,5})?[/]\\d{1,3})?");
        Regex Format = new Regex(decFraction);
        Format.setAllowsInvalid(false);
JFormattedTextField Field = new JFormattedTextField(Format)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `\\d{1,5}([.]\\d{1,3}|(\\s\\d{1,5})?[/]\\d{1,3})?`

This will accept numbers in format

```
xxxxx
xxxxx.yyy
xxxxx_yyyyy/zzz   //_ represents space
xxxxx/zzz
```

Test

```
String regex="\\d{1,5}([.]\\d{1,3}|(\\s\\d{1,5})?[/]\\d{1,3})?";

System.out.println("12345 12/12".matches(regex));   //OK
System.out.println("123/123".matches(regex));       //OK
System.out.println("123.123".matches(regex));       //OK
System.out.println("12345".matches(regex));         //OK
System.out.println("123 /123".matches(regex));      //fail
System.out.println("123 .123".matches(regex));      //fail
System.out.println("/123".matches(regex));          //fail
System.out.println("123/".matches(regex));          //fail
System.out.println("123.".matches(regex));          //fail
System.out.println(".123".matches(regex));          //fail
```

Comment: @Criz check my updated version. I corrected little mistakes that would let regex accept just `1/` or `/2`

Comment: I tried your updated version it doesnt work it only accepts 5digits it doesnt accept the . or the / symbol

Comment: @Criz can I see how you are using this regex? It seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: @Criz It seems that your text field can't accept anything that is not matched by regex and since in the middle of writing you will want to use space and will not have anything after it yet this space will not be allowed. Only way I found for now is just pasting your correct data into that text field.

Comment: @Criz Maybe you should consider creating another question in which you would ask is it possible to allow temporary incorrect data if it leads to correct one using `DefaultFormatter` or something similar.